# Possible DIY fixes for Heater Motor? | heater-blower repair

Tags: jeep, diy, heater-blower, wrangler

***[This didn't get posted apparently cuz i forgot to hit publish, so this was yesterday]***

So i'm streaming live as of now and am diagnosing a problem with the Heater Blower, it's not working. While I was gonna simply replace it, one of my viewers suggested attempting a DIY repair, which I highly agree with, because not only will I save a few bucks (which I have like almost none of T^T), but I can have the a/c fixed quicker. (edit: i will update with photos when i go live again *5:15PM EDT*

### Diagnostic steps me and my twitch chat have done:

- did the obvious thing and connected motor directly to car battery (no result)
- Removed the plastic cover for the motor and inspected the brushes (it is a brushed motor, no clue if DC or AC) *Brushes seemed intact*

(Correct me if im wrong, but I'm pretty sure if material is there, then it's good, and there's a good inch of brush material)

- Tested voltage when spun by hand, (idk if this is important but I know that motors act as generators and generate electricity when spun by something) *generated 1-2 volts (i think) when hand spun*

### things we are gonna try:

- open the motor up more and clean out the carbon dust
- check internal wiring
- (what viewer suggested, good idea?) putting a little solder on each of the little tabs that are on the stater (correct me if im wrong) to help with connection

Any other ideas or ways of fixing? any and all ideas are welcome :)

---

If you need any clarification please let me know. I do tend to over complicate things sometimes and, as a result, my intentions aren't always clear. It's been a problem with me for years and i'm trying my best to improve, so please don't hesitate to ask questions or correct me. I won't be offended.

Comment: It's almost certainly a DC motor.  Since the main power source in most cars is 12V DC, using an AC motor makes little sense.

Comment: How many wires go into the motor?  If its only two, then one will be ground and the other is +12V.   Any other wires could be computer control or sensors or a lockout etc.

Comment: @Criggie - And with only two connections and a DC motor, you can hook the wires up either way and it'll run ... fairly easy to check for operation.

Comment: it was only 2 wires.

Answer (score 0):

The connection between the brushes, and the terminals are corroded
there's a wire that goes from the terminals, coils, then is joined with the braided wire connected to the brushes.

figured this out last stream when I connected the jumper wires directly to the brushes.

so there's a bad connection to the brushes
me and my father are going to drill out the rivets and fix the connection. save me a few hundred bucks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).